# How do I sort two columns in excel by values matching column A?

Tags: excel, vlookup, columnsorting

Hi I have two columns in excel with numbers.
Column A has more numbers than Column B.
I want to sort Column B by values that match in Column A
If the value in column A cannot be found in column B i want column B to display `"MISSING"`
I have already sorted both columns in ascending order.

eg. of the output I want:

```
A       B  
2001    2001  
2002    2002  
2003    MISSING  
2004    2004  
2005    MISSING  
2006    MISSING  
2007    2007
```

Please suggest what formula I should use. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Count the number of occurrences of the value in col A in col B. If the number is 0 then it is missing.

`=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,A1)=0,"Missing",A1)`

Comment: Don't forget to mark it if this is the answer to your questions. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If there aren't too many distinct items, you could just append a list with (a=number, b="MISSING"), order by A and then remove the "MISSING" entry if there are more entries with the same value of A

First part (insert and order) can be done in excel but I think for the second part (removing the "missing" if more entries) you need VBA.

**Update**: based on comments below

Assuming you have an excel table like this:

```
A     B
2001  2001
2001  2003
2002  2005
2003
2004
2004
2005
```

and you'd want something like:

```
A     B
2001  2001
2001  2001
2002  Missing
2003  2003
2004  Missing
2004  Missing
2005  2005
```

You could use something like the following algorithm:

- order the whole table by A
- in column C fill the cells corresponding to the the cells in A with:

  `=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(Ax,$B:$B,1,FALSE)), "Missing", Ax)`

Of course, replace `x` in `Ax` with the index of the cell.

In C you'll have your result with the "Missing" entries.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. I just need to sort column B by values matching in Column A. Column B has fewer items than Column A. If the value in Column A is not in Column B I just want Column B to say "MISSING" - therefore instead of having gaps I will have "MISSING"

Comment: eg. 

2001 2001   
2002 2002  
2003 MISSING    
2004 2004  
2004 MISSING

Answer (score -2):

This formula should work:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(AA,$B:$B,1,FALSE)), "Missing", AA)
```

## NAME?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your answers need to be self-explanatory. You need to mark your code and make it readable.